# Map Marker does not appear

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-studio

I need to add a marker to the map and focus to that marker automatically. I followed instructions of [Map project](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)
Map loads to the fragment but the marker does not appear. I'm a beginner to android. I tried many examples. But did not find the answer. Please help. Ask if any more details needed. Thank you.

**fragment_profile.xml**

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_profile_location"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

**FragmentProfile.java**

```
public class FragmentProfile extends android.app.Fragment{

private GoogleMap googleMap;
private EditText textBirthdate;

public FragmentProfile() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    googleMap = ((MapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map_fragment)).getMapAsync(this););
return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    double latitude = 37;
    double longitude = 127;

    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");
    Log.e("Latitude", "127");
    // adding marker
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 11);
    googleMap.animateCamera(update);
}

}
```

Comment: Add some more code as where you use this method and how you are focusing on that marker

Answer (score 1):

Once you've added the marker to the map, you have to move the "camera" to that position.

```
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11);
        googleMap.animateCamera(update);
```

**Edit**
Don't call your `initializeMap` from `onCreateView` because the MapFragment is not ready yet at this point. You are not seeing the problem because of your try-catch. If you want to see the exceptions logged, use `Log.e(,,e)` instead of `e.printStackTrace`.

So you need to either post your `initializeMap` to a handler or use `getMapAsync` and then, as pRaNaY suggested, implement `OnMapReadyCallback` to get informed of when the map is ready.

**More edit**
After you posted your new code...
First of all, the new code that you posted wouldn't even compile because getMapAsync doesn't return a GoogleMap.
Second, by the time you call `findFragmentById`, the (Child)FragmentManager hasn't yet added the MapsFragment, so not fragment will be found. Move the `findFragmentById` and `getMapAsync` calls to `onResume` or post them to a Handler.

Comment: @Choxmi Do you see a map with no marker or do you see a blank map? You don't need o add `.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory...` as pRaNaY suggested because a default marker is displayed if you provide no custom one. You only need to implement OnMapReadyCallback as he suggested in his edit if you use `getMapAsync()`, but you used `getMap()`.

Comment: See my edit, you are eating a NullPointerException when you try to use the googleMap.

Comment: And your toast will never be shown because that code with the null-check is never executed. By then the NPE has already been thrown and catched by your all-eating try-catch.

Comment: You are correct. I was eating an exception. I implemented OnMapReadyCallback. Now I do not get that exception. But still It is a map with no marker. :(

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `.icon(..)` of MapMarkerOptions.
Like below:

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.your_marker));
.position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");
```

**EDITS:**
You need to implement [OnMapReadyCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback?hl=en) and add marker in `@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
... }`.

```
    @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.your_marker));
.position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");
}
```

See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#add_a_marker)

Comment: I tried tha one earlier. But it did not work @pRaNaY

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the Map on which place the marker. If you do not specify the map on construction of the marker, the marker is created but is not attached/displayed on the map. you may add the marker by calling *setMap()* method.

Here's a sample code for setMap() method:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(47.3732589, 8.2382168));
marker.setMap(map);
```

I hope it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Funally I was able to find the answer with the help of @sorianiv and @pRaNaY . What I did in the final step was, using 
`MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);` 
instead of 
`googleMap = ((MapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map_fragment)).getMapAsync(this););`. 
Thank you guys.